# Oracle: how to deploy a NET stored procedure/function?

Tags: .net, oracle, visual-studio

Oracle 21c. Is it possible to deploy a .NET stored procedure or function manually to a Oracle server?
I have a VS2019+ODP but Oracle Deployment Wizard cannot connect to a database.
That is why my question.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I have changed user/pwd to SYS\**** and it is connected.